# Creation of Unique Index not working using Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have created small mongodb database, I wanted to create **username** column as unique. So I used `createIndex()` command to create index for that column with **UNIQUE** property.

I tried creating unique index using below command in Mongosh.

```js
db.users.createIndex({'username':'text'},{unqiue:true,dropDups: true})
```

For checking current index, I used `getIndex()` command. below is the output for that.

```js
newdb> db.users.getIndexes()
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1 },
    name: 'username_text',
    weights: { username: 1 },
    default_language: 'english',
    language_override: 'language',
    textIndexVersion: 3
  }
]
```

Now Index is created, so for confirmation I checked same in MongoDB Compass.But I am not able to see **UNIQUE** property got assign to my newly created index. Please refer below screenshot.
[MongoDB Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzzWR.png)

I tried deleting old index, as it was not showing UNIQUE property and Created again using MongoDB Compass GUI, and now I can see UNIQUE Property assign to index.
[MongoDB Screentshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2U2x.png)
And below is output for `getIndex()` command in Mongosh.

```js
newdb> db.users.getIndexes()
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1 },
    name: 'username_text',
    unique: true,
    sparse: false,
    weights: { username: 1 },
    default_language: 'english',
    language_override: 'language',
    textIndexVersion: 3
  }
]
```

I tried searching similar topics, but didn't found anything related. Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: At least one problem here is that you have a typo in the command. You have spelled the property as `unqiue` but it should be `unique` (placement of the `i`). But I'm also not sure if text indexes support uniqueness, what is your goal there?

Comment: Oops! my bad, I misspelled the property as unqiue, Thank you @user20042973!  it works now and yes! text indexes support uniqueness I tried.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Yes technically you can create a text index that has the `unique` property, but does it do what you want? The stemming and tokenization seems to cause some interesting behavior with respect to what is considered unique. Can you give some examples of values you would expect to be rejected as being duplicate and those that should be accepted as being unique?

Comment: As I am new to MongoDB, I am creating a simple CRUD API for learning. API will store/read user information and I want `username` as a unique field. So while reading/updating user information I can use the username to search for data in the database. Am I using the right method?

Comment: I think a normal index is probably better suited for your needs here. `db.users.createIndex({'username':1},{unique:true})`. This will enforce uniqueness as you want, and allows for direct querying (as opposed to fuzzy text searching) which seems more applicable to a username field.

Comment: Thank you @user20042973! yes tried the above-mentioned method, and it is working better as it is case sensitive. hence `groOt` and `groot` acting as separate usernames. Thank a lot!

Comment: Sure thing. And if you _wanted_ case insensitivity then you could do that to by using collation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misspelled the property `unique` as `unqiue`, which leads to this issue.
I tried again with the correct spelling, and it is working now.
Sorry for a dumb question